# Antlr4 grammar with basic arithmetic and signed expressions

Tags: java, math, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

I'm learning `Antlr4` to write a language for basic arithmetics. Currently, I have written a grammar with `Antlr4` for the basic arithmetic operators `*` `+` `-` `/`.
Here is my grammar:

```
grammar Expr; // rename to distinguish from Expr.g4

prog:   stat (';' stat)* ;

stat:   ID '=' expr (';'|',')?              # assign
    |   expr (';')?                         # printExpr
    ;

expr:   op=('-'|'+') expr                    # signed
    |   expr op=('*'|'/') expr               # MulDiv
    |   expr op=('+'|'-') expr               # AddSub
    |   ID                                   # id                 
    |   DOUBLE                               # Double
    |   '(' expr ')'                         # parens
    ;



MUL :   '*' ; // assigns token name to '*' used above in grammar
DIV :   '/' ;
ADD :   '+' ;
SUB :   '-' ;
ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]* ;      // match identifiers
DOUBLE :   [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)? ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

The Problem is that my grammar accepts inputs like `2++++3` due to rule: `op=('-'|'+') expr`. However, I didn't find another way to implements signed expressions such as `-2 + 3`, `x = 6; y = -x`, `+3 -2`.

How can I fix the bug?

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking up your grammar, now it is a bit of a monster rule (`expr`). You probably don't want to sign an entire expression, but rather a single value. How about something like this

```
expr: add value
    | expr mult expr
    | expr add expr
    | value
    ;
value: ID
     | DOUBLE
     | '(' expr ')'
     ;
add: '+' | '-';
mult: '*' | '/';
```

This way, you can build signed expressions like `-2`, `+x` or `-(2+3)`, but not `2++3`.